# Libraries in any programming language to implement Round-Robin, First come first serve and Shortest Job first

Tags: algorithm, scheduling

I need libraries in java or C or C++ or python or perl or pascal that implements Round-Robin, First come first serve and Shortest Job first scheduling algorithms??

Comment: ... and a pony. What did you find while looking yourself, and why do you need these three algorithms in six different languages?

Answer (score 3):

This is not reasonably factored out into a library. Instead, it can be trivially be implemented inline.
FIFO is a linked list. Round-Robin is an array of linked lists + an iterator. Shorted Job needs additional information not commonly available in a uniform manner; but then boils down to a priority queue.

All data structures should be available already in basic libraries in most programming languages. You just need to *use* them as desired.